# Reformulating the definition of compactness

Tags: general-topology, definition, education, alternative-proof

Consider the following alternative definition of a topological space.

> **Definition:** A ***topological space*** is an ordered pair $(X, \lessdot)$ consisting of a set $X$ and a binary relation $\lessdot$ between the members of $X$ and the subsets of $X$. (We read $x \lessdot A$ as "$x$ touches $A$".) The *touch relation* $\lessdot$ must satisfy the following axioms:
>
> - No element of $X$ touches the empty set.
> - If $x \in A$, then $x \lessdot A$.
> - If $x \lessdot (A \cup B)$, then $x \lessdot A$ or $x \lessdot B$.
> - If $x \lessdot A$ and every element of $A$ touches $B$, then $x \lessdot B$.

This definition [is equivalent to the usual definition via open sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585941/touch-axiomatization-of-point-set-topology) and better captures the intuition that a topology on a set specifies which points are "infinitesimally close" to each other. It also makes a lot of definitions conceptually easier: for example, $f: X \to Y$ is ***continuous*** iff $x \lessdot A \implies f(x) \lessdot f(A)$.

**Question:** Can the definitions of ***compact spaces*** and ***proper maps*** be reformulated in terms of a touch relation in a simple way, similar in spirit to the definition of continuity above?

Of course, it's possible to define open sets in terms of a touch relation ($A \subseteq X$ is open iff no point of $A$ touches $X \setminus A$) and then restate the usual definition of compactness, but I have a suspicion that something simpler ought to be possible. The definition of continuity above is a lot shorter than "the inverse image under $f$ of every set whose points do not touch its complement is itself a set whose points do not touch its complement." Proper maps, in particular, have a nice intuitive characterization (faraway points are sent to faraway points) that seems compatible with the structure of a touch relation. (Note that $x \not\lessdot A \implies f(x) \not\lessdot f(A)$ doesn't work. Sigmoid functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ have this property but are not proper.)

---

**Aside:** I believe this axiomatization of point-set topology first appeared in a 1977 article by David B. Gauld called ["Nearness - A Better Approach To Topology"](http://www.thebookshelf.auckland.ac.nz/docs/Maths/PDF/mathschron007-007.pdf). In this article, Gauld mentions that

> "...one can formulate a definition of compactness involving nearness spaces, but it is rather unwieldy."

Unfortunately, Gauld does not state his definition, and I can't find any reference to it elsewhere. I caution readers that Gauld's terminology did not catch on, and "nearness space" typically refers to a different mathematical structure elsewhere in the literature.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know, if the following is sufficiently nice for you, but compactness can be characterized as follows:

> **Definition**. A nearness space $(X, \lessdot)$ is compact, iff for any familiy $\mathcal F$ of subsets of $X$ with the finite intersection property, there is some point of $X$ that touches all sets in $\mathcal F$.

We will show that this is equivalent to the usual open set characterisation: Suppose $(X, \lessdot)$ is topologically compact and let $\mathcal F$ a family with the finite intersection property. If $\{X \setminus \bar F: F \in \mathcal F\}$ were an open cover of $X$, is would have a finite subcover, contradicting the finite intersection property. Hence, $\bigcap_{F \in \mathcal F} \bar F \ne \emptyset$, any point in this intersection touches all sets in $\mathcal F$.

On the other side, let $X$ a compact nearness space and $\mathcal U$ an open cover. Suppose $\mathcal U$ doesn't have a finite subcover. Then $\mathcal F := \{X \setminus U: U \in \mathcal U\}$ has the finite intersection property and therefore there is $x \in X$ that touches all sets $X \setminus U$. As all sets $U$ is open, $x$ cannot be contained in any set $U$, Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't $x \lessdot A$ not a fancy way to state $x \in \overline{A}$? So just define $\overline{A} = \{x: x \lessdot A\}$.

The axioms then become more familiar:

- $\overline{\emptyset} = \emptyset$
- $A \subseteq \overline{A}$
- $\overline{A \cup B} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$
- $x \in \overline{A}$ and $A \subseteq \overline{B}$ then $x \in \overline{B}$

The last is a bit weird but the system of axioms is equivalent to the same system but with the 4th replaced by the standard

- $\overline{\overline{A}} = \overline{A}$ for all $A$.

So we just get Kuratowski's closure axioms which are well-known to characterise a topology.

I don't see a lot of independent merit in this particular axiomisation.
The continuity characterisation is just the standard one in terms of closure

- $f:X \to Y$ is continuous iff for all $A \subseteq X$ we have $f[\overline{A}] \subseteq \overline{f[A]}$.

I don't know of any easy characterisation of compactness or properness of maps
in terms of closures e.g. that one could try to translate...

Comment: Yes, this is entirely equivalent to Kuratowski's closure axioms, but I subjectively find the touch axioms easier to motivate and teach than either the closure axioms or the usual open set axioms. It seems more helpful at the undergraduate level for students to think "a topology tells you which points are close together" rather than "a topology says which sets are open/closed"; and as an expositor I regard that as significant independent value.

Comment: @DavidZhang I always explain $\overline{A}$ as the points infinitely close to $A$, intuitively too. Students often know similar set operators (linear span, generated sets etc.in groups, convex span ) so a function mapping sets to nice sets (here: closed) could be very familiar to them.